# Preserve type checking after transpiling flow/typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, flowtype

Currently, if I compile a flow/typescript file from something like the following

```
// @flow

function foo(x: number): string {
    if (x) {
        return String(x);
    }
    return "default string";
}

module.exports = foo;
```

to the following:

```
function foo(x        )         {
    if (x) {
        return String(x);
    }
    return "default string";
}

module.exports = foo;
```

My question is, does there exist a way to transpile the code down to something like following?

```
function foo(x) {
    // preserve typechecking
    if (typeof x !== "number")
        throw new Error(`Expected x to be of type <number> instead got <${typeof x}>!!!!`);

    if (x) {
        return String(x);
    }
    return "default string";
}
```

Comment: This will break quickly as it will not work with interfaces, so it will only be of limited benefit.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth agreed, the compiler could insert code to check conformance to the interface prop by prop but the runtime impact would make it unusable and thus worthless..

Comment: You could conceivable create a compiler transform to achieve this. Add in the code to type check primitives but don't think there something already built for this. @david-sherret does this for nameof you could draw inspiration from it   https://github.com/dsherret/ts-nameof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Microsoft team has decided against the use of preserving type-checking after compiling since that is against their design goals. This was an [issue thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1573) on GitHub.

[Microsoft has stated](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals) in the "non-goals" section, #5, that it will not add/rely on this feature.

However, it is not too difficult to add parameter type checking when it counts.

```
function printMessage(message: string) {

    if (typeof message != "string") 
        throw new Error("printMessage(message): message must be a string.");

    else {
        console.log(message);
    }

}
```

I would like to point out that this isn't something javascript was intentionally designed to do. Fighting the grain can sometimes cause more headaches than it is worth.